# Correlation of model and experimental results

Tags: correlation, model, calibration

I am trying to find a scientifically accepted method to compare my model predictions with experimental values. Here, my model predicts the concentration of DNA as a function of time. DNA concentration is also measured at several points in time *in vivo* in an experimental setting.

Is it valid to compare the model predictions to observed values with a Pearson Correlation Coefficient? Would a considerably big coefficient be taken as an accepted 'method' to prove that model predictions are close to experimental and, thus, that the model is valid?

Comment: Is DNA concentration a viral load? Say more about the experimental design and how the response is measured "as a function of time" (time since infection?)

Comment: If you have quantitative predictions, a correlation coefficient will not be a good comparison. It is possible for observed and predicted to be strongly correlated even while the predictions are quantitatively inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

In medical sciences, calibration can refer to the precision of assays. The goal of your comparison is a calibration study to determine if your model is valid for predicting DNA concentration as a function of time.

The basic concept of a Pearson correlation coefficient is sufficient to identify discrimination: that is that comparing any two observations, better discrimination means that the one with higher predicted values is likely to have higher observed values. This is a result of the fact a correlation coefficient is a weighted average of the pairwise slopes between all observed values.

A negative consequence of the Pearson correlation coefficient is that it is invariant to scale/shift. That means that with an observed sequence [0,1,2,3,4] and predicted sequence [500,505,510,515,520] your agreement is 100% but the predictions are orders of magnitude off.

If you want a measure of predictive accuracy that ranges from -1 to 1 and achieves a value of 1 if and only if the predictions are identical to observed values, fit the following linear model:

$$ E[\text{Observed}_i|\text{Predicted}_i] = 0 + 1 \text{Predicted}_i$$

This can be done with regression through the origin and fitting the predicted value as an offset term. Then, using model statistics, calculate the square root of the $R^2$ coefficient from that. The sign of direction must be found *post-hoc*, but let us assume it's not an issue unless the model in question is terrible.

This model has a correspondence with the [concordance calibration coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) of Lin 1989. There are analogues for mixed/repeated measures designs.

An example of performing such a design is shown here. I am using data from Margaret Pepe's study on inspecting a biomarker's relation to development of AKI (Acute Kidney Injury) following cardiac surgery. The biomarker is longitudinal, but I am using just the first observed value for each patient.

```
aki <- read.csv('http://research.fhcrc.org/content/dam/stripe/diagnostic-biomarkers-statistical-center/files/aki_sim.csv')
aki <- aki[!duplicated(aki$id),]
set.seed(123)
itrain <- sample(1:nrow(aki), nrow(aki)/2)
aki.train <- aki[itrain, ]
aki.test <- aki[-itrain, ]
pred.model <- lm( statusall ~ y, data=aki.train)
pred <- predict(pred.model, newdata=aki.test)

plot(pred, aki.test$statusall, xlab='Predicted status', 
  ylab='Observed status \n(0: no AKI, 1: mild AKI, 2: severe AKI, 9: death)')
abline(0,1)
calib.model <- lm(statusall ~ 0 + offset(pred), data=aki.test)
```

Gives:

[image]

> summary(calib.model)

```
Call:
lm(formula = statusall ~ 0 + offset(pred), data = aki.test)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6599 -0.4257 -0.3525 -0.2539  8.7043 

No Coefficients

Residual standard error: 0.9518 on 900 degrees of freedom
```

So $\sqrt{1-0.9518}$ gives a calibration coefficient of 0.22 which is very poor. This is likely a result of the ordinal encoding of AKI severity which includes 9 as death from AKI. Obviously, biological measurements like creatinine clearance would be preferable.

Excluding "9"s as deaths: the R^2 is much better:

```
> calib.model <- lm(statusall ~ 0 + offset(pred), data=aki.test, subset=statusall != 9)
> summary(calib.model)

Call:
lm(formula = statusall ~ 0 + offset(pred), data = aki.test, subset = statusall != 
    9)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6599 -0.4269 -0.3528 -0.2570  1.8659 

No Coefficients

Residual standard error: 0.6419 on 894 degrees of freedom
```

Gives a calibration coefficient of `sqrt(1-0.6419)` = 0.60 which is still low.

A last issue to consider is: what is the appropriate scale on which to calibrate the expected and observed values? The raw scale is nice because it is interpretable, but DNA concentrations are often measured on a log scale or a complementary log-log scale. Consider these changes of variable based on your knowledge of the problem.

Comment: @PaulP you'll have to use the comments here to get any reliable feedback from me. It's an interesting method. I used a small example with simulated data from Margaret Pepe who's very respected in the field for predictive biological models. I saw the post nonetheless and expanded the answer to include a small example. I think you may have to open some other questions if you need specific clarification on what an offset is.

Comment: AdamO thanks a lot! I will try to get the most out of this example.

Comment: Just to mention that while searching I found this really 'soft' software (MedCalc) that seems to perform the Concordance correlation coefficient method in a very user-friendly way.